# Conditional expectation of multivariate normal distribution with inequality condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be jointly normal with means $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$ and covariances  $\sigma_{ij}$. I know that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1\mid X_2=x_2]=\mu_1+\frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_2^2}(x_2-\mu_2)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1\mid X_2<x_2]=\mu_1-\sigma_{12}\frac{\phi(\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})}{\Phi(\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})}
$$
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the density and probability distribution functions for the standard normal distribution. Is there a similar expression for
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1\mid X_2=x_2,X_3<x_3]~?
$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you derive the first 2 expectations or were they given?

Comment: $$ \operatorname E(X_1\mid X_2=x_2) = \mu_1 + \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_2^2} (x_2-\mu_2), $$ with a "plus" sign. Note that if $\sigma_{12}>0$ then this conditional expectation should _increase_ as $x_2$ increases.

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing out the typo in my derivation, I've corrected it.

Comment: $(X_1, X_3)|X_2 = x_2$ has a bivariate normal distribution. Then you can apply your second formula.

Comment: How did you get your conditional expectation given $X_2<x_2$? You've written an expression that does not depend on $\mu_2. \qquad$

Comment: BGM has the right idea, but I have qualms about your second formula. And I'd have written $(X_1,X_3)\mid X_2=x_2$ rather than $(X_1,X_3)|X_2=x_2. \qquad$

Comment: As per the accepted answer, shouldn't the second equation have $\sigma_{12}/\sigma_{2}$ instead of just $\sigma_{12}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\operatorname E(X_1\mid X_3<x_3)$ I'm getting
$$
\operatorname E(X_1\mid X_3<x_3) = \mu_1 - \frac{\sigma_{13}}{\sigma_3} \cdot \frac{\varphi\left( \dfrac{x_3-\mu_3}{\sigma_3} \right)}{\Phi\left( \dfrac{x_3-\mu_3}{\sigma_3} \right)}. \tag 1
$$
Once you're given $X_2=x_2,$ you have a certain conditional probability distribution of $(X_1,X_3),$ which is bivariate normal with expected value given by
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(X_1\mid X_2=x_2) = \mu_1 + \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_2^2} ( x_2-\mu_2 ), \\[10pt]
& \operatorname E(X_3\mid X_2=x_2) = \mu_3 + \frac{\sigma_{32}}{\sigma_2^2} ( x_2-\mu_2 ),
\end{align}
and variance given by
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{var}(X_1\mid X_2=x_2) = \sigma_1^2 - \frac{\sigma_{12}^2}{\sigma_2^2}, \\[10pt]
& \operatorname{var}(X_3\mid X_2=x_2) = \sigma_3^2 - \frac{\sigma_{23}^2}{\sigma_2^2}, \\[10pt]
& \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_3\mid X_2=x_2) = \sigma_{13} - \frac{\sigma_{12} \sigma_{23}}{\sigma_2^2}.
\end{align}
Now apply line $(1)$ above but with these conditional expectations and conditional variances. Where you had $\sigma_{13}$ in line $(1),$ you'll have $\sqrt{\sigma_{13} - \frac{\sigma_{12} \sigma_{23}}{\sigma_2^2}},$ etc.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, thanks a lot Michael! I have corrected my second formula as well. After conditioning $(1)$ on $X_2=x_2$ as you suggested, I was able to obtain the final answer.

Comment: @JasonV : Recall that you can "accept" this answer.

Comment: I did not notice that convenient feature, your answer has been accepted.

Comment: @JasonV : Thank you.

Comment: @JasonV : There was a typo that I just fixed. It should say "Where you had $\sigma_{13}$ in line $(1),$ you'll have $\sqrt{\sigma_{13} - \frac{\sigma_{12} \sigma_{23}}{\sigma_2^2}}. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out and fix the typo. I was focusing on understanding the logic behind your derivation in order to obtain mine so I didn't notice it when I read your answer.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, The (1) should be: $E[X_1|X_3<x_3]=\mu_1-\cdots$. (Consider the case of $X_1=X_3$ and $x_3=\mu_1$, $E[X_1|X_1<\mu_1]<\mu_1$).